# String to number JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, math, numbers

Why is my code not working correctly?

(Sorry, I'm not good in English to explain, not my fault)

HTML:

```
<input type="text"  id="euro" /> € = <span id="coins"></span> Miitomo Coins

<button onclick="ok()">Convert</button>
```

JS code:

```
function ok() {
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = a + 100;
}

var a = document.getElementById("euro").value;
```

Comment: You probably want to get the value from the input field when you click the button, so move it into the `ok()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- You must define the input field and not the value
- You must use `parseInt()`

Code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("euro");
function ok()
{
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = parseInt(input.value) + 100;
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to put the parseInt()?

Comment: @TheUserNo2017 on the `input.value`

Answer (score 1):

First, grab the value of the field when the button is clicked so you have the current content:

```
function ok() {
    var val = document.getElementById( "euro" ).value;
    ...
}
```

Then, convert the value that you grabbed to a number. Content in the DOM is always a string:

```
function ok() {
    var val = document.getElementById( "euro" ).value;
    var eurosNumber = Number( val );
    ...
}
```

Note that I'm using `Number` instead of `parse*`.

I'm assuming that you may type either an integer (`1`, `20`, `25`, etc.) or a fractional number (`1.50`, `10.25`, `20.34`, etc.) into the field.

You can do the same conversion with `parseFloat` or `parseInt` but this is more explicit that you're converting `[some string]` to a `Number`.

Just watch out: if the string isn't a valid number, there will be an error (`Number( [not a number] )` will return `NaN`)!

Finally, do your addition:

```
function ok() {
    var val = document.getElementById( "euro" ).value;
    var eurosNumber = Number( val );

    document.getElementById( "coins" ).innerHTML = eurosNumber + 100;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that `Number` is more *"explicit"* but I would argue that if decimal input is expected, it's usage (or just unary coercion) is favourable over `parseInt` due to quirky historical behaviours cross-browser - and the fact that best practice dictates you should always specify the radix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the input value in the ok function and to use parseInt or parseFloat:

```
<input type="text"  id="euro" /> € = <span id="coins"></span> Miitomo Coins
<button onclick="ok()">Convert</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ok() {
      var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("euro").value);
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = a + 100;
}
```

JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zbL83cbu/3/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("euro").value);
```

Use `parseInt()`